# Parsing string in PHP and create an array

Tags: php, arrays

Hi Can anyone please help me in parsing the below string in PHP and make it as array

The value are seperated by **`;`**

**String Value**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Set-Cookie: LWSSO_COOKIE_KEY=UUo07jYJvrMtRg_GbKTV5Tf2hmI6N4XQRyVR7lLl9M6PphiPdmSWwLU7Pr1ZMRra10gv4HGLw9PlKDvyhPD0Z23u-Mv2S8zXf5Jgt67JGOV06J7d3I_ne7KmbbhwBIpvisedcBhBDLXfrOP-aFvJvdYekAtikN0GAU4Q2eTt1GWxPOJrRQUS2sSWXKC0A5NKUszUwkg11oBe-sXhsLmy5NiSDSErGNt_XBowWA-AgT2CFlB3J-xpUQ1xupJ8rs4H3A1u8zIGtlIWKtawLQLaKQYhQwr8DXnJUxpt0YNiyEg.;Path=/;HTTPOnly
Set-Cookie: QCSession=NzE1ODE1MjtlYlZOalo2eGNwNkFyOXdpVE52Q0RRKio7UkVTVCBjbGllbnQ7IDsg;Path=/;HttpOnly
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Set-Cookie: ALM_USER=b3a903d0544b5aaa1f150e2b8f6ad420b4e8ad33dea552dacd02479c4f07fe41;Path=/
Set-Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=ad3d73000606ca7bf6aa5773344720f7bbe0201c154e51c8a770a0bb29e0db38;Path=/
Content-Length: 0
Server: Jetty(9.1.4.v20140401)
```

Now I want the array with below values

```
[Set-Cookie: LWSSO_COOKIE_KEY] => UUo07jYJvrMtRg_GbKTV5Tf2hmI6N4XQRyVR7lLl9M6PphiPdmSWwLU7Pr1ZMRra10gv4HGLw9PlKDvyhPD0Z23u-Mv2S8zXf5Jgt67JGOV06J7d3I_ne7KmbbhwBIpvisedcBhBDLXfrOP-aFvJvdYekAtikN0GAU4Q2eTt1GWxPOJrRQUS2sSWXKC0A5NKUszUwkg11oBe-sXhsLmy5NiSDSErGNt_XBowWA-AgT2CFlB3J-xpUQ1xupJ8rs4H3A1u8zIGtlIWKtawLQLaKQYhQwr8DXnJUxpt0YNiyEg.

[Set-Cookie: QCSession] => NzE1ODE1MjtlYlZOalo2eGNwNkFyOXdpVE52Q0RRKio7UkVTVCBjbGllbnQ7IDsg
```

I have tried below code

```
$response = 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Set-Cookie: LWSSO_COOKIE_KEY=UUo07jYJvrMtRg_GbKTV5Tf2hmI6N4XQRyVR7lLl9M6PphiPdmSWwLU7Pr1ZMRra10gv4HGLw9PlKDvyhPD0Z23u-Mv2S8zXf5Jgt67JGOV06J7d3I_ne7KmbbhwBIpvisedcBhBDLXfrOP-aFvJvdYekAtikN0GAU4Q2eTt1GWxPOJrRQUS2sSWXKC0A5NKUszUwkg11oBe-sXhsLmy5NiSDSErGNt_XBowWA-AgT2CFlB3J-xpUQ1xupJ8rs4H3A1u8zIGtlIWKtawLQLaKQYhQwr8DXnJUxpt0YNiyEg.;Path=/;HTTPOnly
    Set-Cookie: QCSession=NzE1ODE1MjtlYlZOalo2eGNwNkFyOXdpVE52Q0RRKio7UkVTVCBjbGllbnQ7IDsg;Path=/;HttpOnly
    Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
    Set-Cookie: ALM_USER=b3a903d0544b5aaa1f150e2b8f6ad420b4e8ad33dea552dacd02479c4f07fe41;Path=/
    Set-Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=ad3d73000606ca7bf6aa5773344720f7bbe0201c154e51c8a770a0bb29e0db38;Path=/
    Content-Length: 0
    Server: Jetty(9.1.4.v20140401)';

function get_headers_from_curl_response($response)
{
    $headers = [];

    $header_text = substr($response, 0, strpos($response, "\r\n\r\n"));

    foreach (explode("\r\n", $header_text) as $i => $line)
        if ($i === 0)
            $headers['http_code'] = $line;
        else {
            list ($key, $value) = explode(': ', $line);

            $headers[$key] = $value;
        }

    return $headers;
}

$headers = get_headers_from_curl_response($response);
print_r($headers);
```

But I am getting only

```
Array
(
    [http_code] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    [Set-Cookie] => XSRF-TOKEN=4891ba55b486a006c130679763e369e15f309fbd6254c7e9c92bc8493f48eccd;Path=/
    [Expires] => Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
    [Content-Length] => 0
    [Server] => Jetty(9.1.4.v20140401)
)
```

Comment: Is that one, long string? You could do this by stripping off all the things you don't need, and then use explode(), but it would be prudent to know if it's one long string, or multiple strings.

Comment: I just updated my approach can u please check that and see what i have done wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work perfectly

```
<?php

$string = 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Set-Cookie: LWSSO_COOKIE_KEY=UUo07jYJvrMtRg_GbKTV5Tf2hmI6N4XQRyVR7lLl9M6PphiPdmSWwLU7Pr1ZMRra10gv4HGLw9PlKDvyhPD0Z23u-Mv2S8zXf5Jgt67JGOV06J7d3I_ne7KmbbhwBIpvisedcBhBDLXfrOP-aFvJvdYekAtikN0GAU4Q2eTt1GWxPOJrRQUS2sSWXKC0A5NKUszUwkg11oBe-sXhsLmy5NiSDSErGNt_XBowWA-AgT2CFlB3J-xpUQ1xupJ8rs4H3A1u8zIGtlIWKtawLQLaKQYhQwr8DXnJUxpt0YNiyEg.;Path=/;HTTPOnly
Set-Cookie: QCSession=NzE1ODE1MjtlYlZOalo2eGNwNkFyOXdpVE52Q0RRKio7UkVTVCBjbGllbnQ7IDsg;Path=/;HttpOnly
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Set-Cookie: ALM_USER=b3a903d0544b5aaa1f150e2b8f6ad420b4e8ad33dea552dacd02479c4f07fe41;Path=/
Set-Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=ad3d73000606ca7bf6aa5773344720f7bbe0201c154e51c8a770a0bb29e0db38;Path=/
Content-Length: 0
Server: Jetty(9.1.4.v20140401)';

$array_start = explode(';',$string);

foreach ($array_start as $key => $value) {
    $remove_from_string = ['HTTP/1.1 200 OK','Path=/','HTTPOnly','HttpOnly','Content-Length',': 0'];
    $replace_array = ['','','','','',''];
    $value = str_replace($remove_from_string,$replace_array,$value);
    $value = trim(preg_replace(('/Expires: [a-zA-Z]+, [0-9]+ [a-zA-Z]+ [0-9]+ [0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+ [a-zA-Z]+/'), '', $value));
    $value = trim(preg_replace(('/Server: [a-zA-Z0-9.\(\)]+/'),'',$value));
    if (!empty($value)) {
        $new_array[trim(explode('=',$value)[0])] = explode('=',$value)[1];   
    }
}
$good = ['Set-Cookie: LWSSO_COOKIE_KEY','Set-Cookie: QCSession','Set-Cookie: ALM_USER'];
$result = array_intersect_key($new_array,array_flip($good));

echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
echo '</pre>';

?>
```

Comment: Now you can get the ALM_USER as well, as well as the last entry, the `Set-Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN` if you add that as well to the `$good`-array.